# What to do if you say the wrong version of the last bracha in Shmoneh Esrei?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes

There are generally two texts for the last bracha of Shmoneh Esrei - one beginning *Sim Shalom*, and one that starts *Shalom Rav*. There are different customs for when each is said.

If someone says the wrong one according to his custom (e.g. *Sim Shalom* at Shabbat Mincha outside of Israel) but would be correct according to a different custom (inside Israel) - what should be done?

What about if someone says the wrong one according to all customs (e.g. *Shalom Rav* at Shacharit)?

Comment: FWIW, your first example isn't great, there are Ashkenazi communities in chu"l where Sim Shalom is said (French and German communities, in my experience).

Comment: [Nusach Provence](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A1) has (had) *shalom rav* at all *tefillot*, including *shacharit*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rema ( OC 127:2):

The Rema says that the custom is to say Sim Shalom during Shacharis and any other Tefillah that is fitting to have a Birkas Cohanim i.e. Mussaf (of Shabbos Rosh Codesh or Chag), and the Minchah of a Fast Day.

> Biur Halacha:
>
> a)    The Minhag according to the Arizal (Chasidim) is to say Sim Shalom
>   all the times. According to the Aruch Hasulchan this is also the
>   Minhag of Sefardim.
>
> b)    **If you said Shalom Rav during a time when you should have said
>   Sim Shalom you don’t have to daven again.**
>
> c)    If you are still in the middle of the Beracho and you realize you
>   said Shalom Rav erroneously you should go back to the beginning of the
>   Beracho. **If the opposite happened you would not have to go back
>   since you said a lengthier version this will suffice.**

Source :

http://israel.aish.com/smicha/RavCableSugyos/HilchosTfilah/Review%20Sheet%20for%20Mistakes%20in%20Davening.doc